# Uipath problem of extracting data from table that contains a click to an additional data

Tags: uipath, rpa

I need to extract data from a table in which each row contains a button that needs to be clicked to obtain additional information. i extraced the first table and i added a for each to click on the other button to extract more information but it doesn't work

i used Data Scraping" wizard in UiPath to extract the table data into a DataTable variable.
i Used a "For Each Row" activity to loop through each row of the DataTable.
Within the "For Each Row" activity, i used a "Click" activity to click on the button in the current row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So far sounds good, and what is your issue?

Comment: i extract the users from a web page with table extraction and the i used for each row in that datatable and inside that loop i used a an open browser that indicate in wich i put the URL that i change it into this "https://localhost:9443/carbon/user/view-roles.jsp?username="+CurrentRow("Name").ToString()+"&displayName="+CurrentRow("Name").ToString()+"" now i inside the activity( open browser) i added a  table extraction for the roles but the data table shows 0 rows ( i checked the extraction without the for each activity and it works ) so this is the problem